# Fibonacci Identity Proof

Tags: proof-writing, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

I'm having a bit of trouble proving the following identity, where $F_n$ represents the $n$th Fibonacci number. The identity is 
$$ \frac{1}{F_{2n}} = \frac{F_{n-1}}{F_n} - \frac{F_{2n-1}}{F_{2n}}$$
where $n$ is even and positive.

Comment: Have you tried... induction?

Comment: Yes but since n has to be even that made things a bit more complicated

Comment: although is ugly, maybe you can use the explicit formula for $F_{n}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We shall show the following formula by induction (The required equation is implied by this.)
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{n-1}F_{2n}=(-1)^nF_n+F_nF_{2n-1}
\end{eqnarray*}
Observe that the recurrence relation can be rewritten as
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{2n+2}=2F_{2n+1}-F_{2n}+F_{2n-2}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So now 
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{n}F_{2n+2}=(F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})(2F_{2n+1}-F_{2n}+F_{2n-2})
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the inductive hypothesis on $F_{n-1}F_{2n}$ & $ F_{n-2}F_{2n-2}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
F_{n}F_{2n+2}=-(-1)^nF_n-F_nF_{2n-1}+(-1)^{n-1}F_{n-1}+F_{n-1}F_{2n-3}+2F_{n-1}F_{2n+1}+F_{n-1}F_{2n-2}+2F_{n-2}F_{2n+1}-F_{n-2}F_{2n}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now several applications of $F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$ & the result follows.